# Select the last element in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the last element in my table. I did it fortunately but the problem is the fact that the insertion in my loop is always duplicate the entry in my second table. I have my scrip here and I don't know what is the problem.

I found a way to avoid by checking if the last entry has not been inserted yet but it doesn't work.

```
$p = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM messagein ORDER BY `Id` DESC limit 1 ");

//  SELECT * FROM messagein WHERE Id = (select MAX('Id') from messagein)

echo "<table style='border-width: 1px solid black;'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> ID </td>";
echo "<td> SendTime </td>";
echo "<td> ReceiveTime </td>";
echo "<td> MessageFrom </td>";
echo "<td> MessageTo </td>";
echo "<td> MessageText </td>";
echo "<td> MessageType </td>";
echo "</tr>";

while ($data = $p->fetch())
    {

    // $p = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM messagein ORDER BY `Id` DESC limit 1");
    // $data = $p->fetch();

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $data['Id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data['SendTime'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>" . $data['ReceiveTime'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>" . $data['MessageFrom'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>" . $data['MessageTo'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>" . $data['MessageText'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>" . $data['MessageType'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    if (substr($data['MessageText'], 0, 3) == "lat")
        {
        $final = explode(" ", $data['MessageText']);
        $latitude = substr($final['0'], 4);
        $longitude = substr($final['1'], 5);
        $vitesse = substr($final['2'], 6);
        $temps = $data['ReceiveTime'];
        $exists = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM donneesgps WHERE latitude = ? AND longitude = ? AND temps = ? AND vitesse = ?");
        $response = $exists->execute(array(
            $latitude,
            $longitude,
            $temps,
            $vitesse
        ));
        echo $response;
        if ($response == true)
            {
            $donneesgps = "INSERT INTO donneesgps (latitude, longitude, temps, vitesse)
                           VALUES ('$latitude', '$longitude', '$temps', '$vitesse')";
            $pdo->exec($donneesgps);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: not concerning the specific question but why do you prepare the select but not the insert? the result from execute is false if the query is invalid (meaning broken ... syntactically).

Comment: not sure what is the problem, plese show us sample data current and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a SELECT at all.

Comment: Thanks Juan Carlos. my problem is that the by refreshing the page, it insert a new line automatically. What I is to check if the entry has not been inserted yet before the insertion

Comment: If I have a new line inserted in the first table "messagein" I do a formatage and store differents elements in the second table "donneesgps"

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have only one row from the database, then don't use "while".

Just:

```
$data = $p->fetch();
if (!empty($data['Id'])){
  // Do your stuff
}
```

You will have probably some issue because you are using in your loop the same object $pdo by executing queries like that in the fly.

From my opinion, you should store before all the "SELECT" results into arrays, and then display it dynamically into HTML table (following MVC methods)

Comment: I have many rows and the "while" is because I want to permanently check if I got a new incoming message from the GPS tracker

Comment: "SELECT * FROM messagein ORDER BY `Id` DESC limit 1" will return you maximum 1 row as your script "say". "While" won't loop "permanently" but according to the number of rows returned (and here, only one, that is to say the last entry of your table). It is your whole script that should permanently run in a loop to check if you have new message into your database.

Comment: @CyrilleBelcoIer "permanently" checking is interesting. How do you ensure you won't miss an entry? (if gps inserts 2 or more entries at once)

Comment: A PHP script can't run eternally. You must request it. You can make an HTML page that displays initially the data you have at this instant, and then having some Javascript to execute into "interval" (for example, each second) a request to your PHP file that will return "JSON" response containing the data you need. I think having an API and using AJAX is what you need

Comment: Jakumi I'm very interested in your idea I'm working on it. If you get something about please share it here for us. @FragBis thanks for your suggestion. That is what I need

Answer (score 0):

You check the return value of `{pdostatement}->execute()` which will return `FALSE` when the query is invalid and could not be executed. Since your query is apparently valid and was executed, it will almost always return `TRUE` which is completely unrelated to the row already existing or not.

You should `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` instead and see if the actual value of `fetch` is 0 or 1 (or more).

Alternatively, you could just make lat/long/temps/vitesse a primary key and `INSERT IGNORE` all the time.

In any case you should make the insert also a prepared statement.